# d3.js in Angular Ui-router template

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angular-ui-router

Has anyone successfully rendered d3 in an Angular ui-router template?

I've been unable to do so. The visual simply does not appear but throws no exceptions. I've set my canvas size very large to see if it is rendering elsewhere without success. I have also put the template in various paths of my file system, no luck.

I can get the visual to display in the template just fine when rendering the code as its own page. It does not transfer during $state templating.

Bostock and the examples I've seen build the visual into a directive.

Plunk of a basic example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PCRsDG9s9MG2Y2wqkJ56?p=catalogue

Comment: Can you post some of the code you tried?

Comment: Done: http://plnkr.co/edit/PCRsDG9s9MG2Y2wqkJ56?p=catalogue